# Proofs in Beamer

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, theorems

I'm writing a presentation in Beamer, where I present proofs which are longer than one frame. How to make Beamer to break it automatically to another frame? If it is not possible how am I supposed to remove the square (the end of proof) and put it in a right place in another frame?

Comment: Please check for the `allowframebreaks` option [in the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer)

Comment: @percusse I don't think `allowframebreaks` will work when using the proof environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Indeed, you are right. That was a tongue-in-cheek comment as I wasn't sure if that would do it..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using the `proof` environment, then I am afraid that there's no automatic way to break the text (`allowframebreaks` won't work here, since we're dealing with a block).

You can define an environment that behaves as `proof`, but without using the end-mark; you then can use this new environment for the first frames of the proof and then, use the standard `proof` environment for the last frame; here's an example of the definition of such environment (which I called `proofs`) and its ussage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As requested in a comment, I have defined now three new environments: `proofs`, which uses a block with title given by `\insertproofname` (default "Proof") and suppresses the end-mark; `proofc`, which suppresses both the title and the end-mark, and `proofe` which suppresses the title but adds the end-mark; the first environment is to be used to start the proof, the second one, to continue the proof, and the third one, to end the proof:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\newenvironment<>{proofc}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{proof begin}{\begin{block}{}}
    \par
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}}
  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\newenvironment<>{proofe}{%
    \par
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \setbeamertemplate{proof begin}{\begin{block}{}}
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}}
  {\popQED\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofc}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofc}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofe}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofe}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, probably the only possible solution. Would it be possible to modify it? I would prefer to have no name such as Proof (Cont.) on the second, third and so on slides..only Proof on the first slide and the square on the last slide.

Comment: @Laura sure; I've updated my answer implementing the necessary environments. On a side note, don't forget to accept my answer if you consider it solved your problem; in case of doubt on how/why to accept answers, plese see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 12):

One option to solve this is by 'brute force': since there exists the generic **block** environment for beamer classes, we can do the following:

```
    \begin{frame}

    \begin{block}{Proof}
    Here is the first part of my proof.
    \end{block}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}

    \begin{block}{}
    This is where my proof continues, and ends.
    \qed
    \end{block}

    \end{frame}
```

Inside the second empty `{}' we can insert anything we would like our block to have as a title, or just leave it empty if we don't want anything there.

Comment: +1 Very simple  useful solution !!

Comment: To eliminate the extra space of the empty block title you can also use `\begin{block}{\vspace*{-1em}}`

Answer (score 0):

The `allowframebreaks` option is evil, but just as a proof of concept, here a solution with the `tcolorbox` inner theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{breakable,title after break=\insertblocktitle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\framebreak
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I noticed that if I add in the preamble the line `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]`, then is not splitting well.

Comment: @Oromion It should work as long as you load the tcolorbox inner theme *after* the `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]` (or remove `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]` altogether, it won't have any effect on the tcolorboxes.)

Comment: Thanks! It is working. https://i.imgur.com/y76lUcV.png

Comment: @Oromion Glad to hear it is working! I added this information to the theme documentation so it will be included in the next version of the theme.