# Breaking a proof between frames

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, theorems

I have the same question in here

[Proofs in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/proofs-in-beamer?rq=1)

In the answer, the author used `beamertemplate` to examine breaking the frames. But how can i change it to my paragraph?

For example, i need to insert the following problem and its solution

Problem : Solve 
`x^{3} - x -3=2\sqrt[3]{6x-3x^{2}}`

Proof : Put `a:=\sqrt[3]{6x-3x^2}` to obtain a system

`\begin{eqnarray}x^3-x-3 &=& 2a\\6x-3x^2 &=& a^3\end{eqnarray}`

Add the equations up to get

`x^3-3x^2+5x-3=a^3+2a`

`(x-1)^3+2(x-1)=a^3+2a`

Put `y:=x-1` to get

`y^3+2y=a^3+2a`

`(y-a)(y^2+ay+a^2+2)=0`

The second factor is obviously always positive, hence `y=a\iff a=x-1`

Now `(1)` yields `x^3-x-3=2x-2\iff x^3-3x=1`

Put `x:=2t` to get

`8t^3-6t=1\iff 4t^3-3t={1\over 2}`

By addition formulas, there must exist `\phi` such that `t=\cos\phi`, yielding

`\cos 3\phi={1\over 2}\iff 3\phi=\pm{\pi\over 3}+2k\pi\iff \phi=\pm{\pi\over 9}+{2k\pi\over 3},k\in\mathbb{Z}`

Now `x=2\cos\phi=2\cos\left(\pm{\pi\over 9}+{2k\pi\over 3}\right)`, i.e.

`x\in\left\{2\cos{\pi\over 9},2\cos{5\pi\over 9},2\cos{7\pi\over 9}\right\}`

It may take more than one frame and i think the command `allowbreakframes` is useful. But i don't know how to exchange `beamertemplate` to my above paragraph. I also want to put the problem and the solution in blocks. Thanks for your listening my question!

Comment: Please add a `minimal working example` so we know what you tried so far. So far your question seems unclear what you're aiming at.

Comment: Hi Nhật Tân Trần and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Dear @MarcoDaniel, thanks for your comments. I'm not familiar with this website because I'm a beginner. I'm trying to express my question, but I'm sorry if it didn't. I wanted to ask someone for breaking a proof between frames because sometimes it takes more than one frame. I understood the answer in current post, but i don't know where can I insert my code into that environment?

Comment: We don't know your code. Providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is the best tool to show your issue.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, I edited my question. Please help me if you have time.