# Global options for \proofname

Tags: beamer, environments, page-breaking

I am using a proofs block similar to the one described in [Proofs in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/proofs-in-beamer) and cannot seem to figure out how to keep a consistent proofnam over multiple blocks. Basically, is there a way to allow proofname to take a new global value until a command resets back to default?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but are you maybe asking for `{
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Quack}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}
}`? The group `{}` around this will make sure that the redefinition of the proofname only changes the title within this group

Comment: I imagine this would work well for smaller cases but this seems to considerably extend my runtime, given my use of 3 proofs blocks and other elements like a remark block and a figure across 4 frames.

Comment: What does it matter how many frames there are? You can place as many frames as you want into the group.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad, works like a charm now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily redefine the name by doing it inside a group `{...}`. The group around it will make sure that the redefinition of the proofname only changes the title within this group:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{proofs}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

{
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Quack}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proofs}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proofs}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}[\proofname\ (Cont.)]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```